# Sum per quarter with extra bits

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table that looks like this

| Date | Transaction |
| --- | --- |
| 01/05/2011 | £100,000 |
| 07/06/2011 | £200,000 |
| 10/07/2011 | £123,123 |

And so on, the data continues from 2011 to 2024 and is about 200 entries,

I'm trying to work out how to have a formula in the next cols that sums per quarter e.g

Q2 2011 - £300k
Q3 2011 - £123,123

and also in another column the last date of that quarter that was counted e.g.

Q2 2011 would be 07/06/2011

sometimes I have more than one entry per month, so just pulling out the last date that was Mar/Jun/Sep/Dec doesn't work for me

Comment: Use a pivot table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum per month with extra bits](https://superuser.com/questions/1827931/sum-per-month-with-extra-bits)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Excel Formulas` it can be accomplished like as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _date, A2:A4,
     _transaction, B2:B4,
     _quarter, "Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(_date)/3,0)&" "&YEAR(_date),
     _output, DROP(GROUPBY(_quarter,HSTACK(_transaction,_date),HSTACK(SUM,MAX),,0),1),
     VSTACK({"Quarters","SumsPer Quarters","LastDateOf ThatQuarter"},_output))
```

---

- Note that the above formula works with `MS365` Version of Excel with the `Beta Channel` Enabled.
- `_date` --> Variable returns the date range `A2:A4`,
- `_transaction` --> Variable returns the transaction range `B2:B4`,
- `_quarter` --> Variable returns the quarters per year

---

```
"Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(_date)/3,0)&" "&YEAR(_date)
```

---

- `_output` --> Variable returns the output desired.

---

```
DROP(GROUPBY(_quarter,HSTACK(_transaction,_date),HSTACK(SUM,MAX),,0),1)
```

---

- While using with `VSTACK()` it creates a headers along with the `_output`

---

```
VSTACK({"Quarters","SumsPer Quarters","LastDateOf ThatQuarter"},_output)
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Transactiontbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Transactiontbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Transaction", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Quarter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Quarter", each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Quarter", {{"Quarter", each "Q" & Text.From(_, "en-US"), type text}}),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Prefix", "Year", each Date.Year([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Inserted Year", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Quarter", "Year"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Period"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"Period"}, {{"SumsPer Quarter", each List.Sum([Transaction]), type nullable number}, {"LastDateOf ThatQuarter", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

However, using `Pivot Table` it can also be achieved, but one helper column is needed.

[image]

---

- Insert the formula in the adjacent column of `Transactions`

---

```
="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(H2)/3,0)&" "&YEAR(H2)
```

---

- Select any cell in the data and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> which opens the `Pivot Table` Wizard.
- From the `Wizard` click on `Next` Twice and in the `Step 3` click on `NewSheet` or `Existing Sheet` with the desired cell reference to place the `Pivot Table`
- In the `Rows` Area keep the `Quarters` while the `Transactions` & `Date` in the `Values` Area, ensure to click the summarize option for the first one as `SUM` while for the latter as `MAX`.
- Change the layout to tabular and may switch off the Grandtotals as per preferences.

---

Last but not least with some basic approaches which should work with `Excel 2010`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J19</kbd>

```
="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(H19)/3,0)&" "&YEAR(H19)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L19</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Quarters,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS(L$18:L18,Quarters),0)),"")
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M19</kbd>

```
=SUMIF(Quarters,L19,Transaction)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N19</kbd>

```
=MAX((L19=Quarters)*Date)
```

---

For the above i have used defined named ranges, which can be named using from the `Name Manager` under `Formulas Tab`

---

**Note:** Please make sure to change the cell references or ranges as per your suit. File for download --> **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckiZ-vOqg_rEqq4m0?e=sY3kWi)**